# Creating/Updating Social Tables tags

Tags: social-tables

I am trying to create tags with specific colors via the Social Tables API.

I am able to create tags on a guest as a list. For example: `"tags": ["Male", "Advisor"]`

If I try to do this and assign a color as is outlined in the documentation as follows:

```
"tags": [
    {
      "title": "Male",
      "color": "#B3D4FF"
    },
    {
      "title": "Advisor",
      "color": "#EFED75"
    }
]
```

I get a 500 status with the following error:

```
{
  "code": "Internal",
  "message": "TypeError: tag.trim is not a function"
}
```

I have also tried creating and editing the tags from the tags API endpoint but I can't get either of those to work either.

An example of how to do this correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the POST /4.0/guestlists/{guestlist_id}/tags endpoint to add one tag at a time.

```
{
    "tag": {
        "title": "Male",
        "color": "#EFED75"
    }
}
```

Then you can reference the tag by name when you add/update a guest.